Estimating a weight function in a smooth domain
Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\sigma\in(\frac{1}{2},1)$.
In the book of Grisvard  "Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains", Page 19, Formula (1.3.2.12), the author gave an estimate to $$
\rho(x)= \int_{\Omega^c} \frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+2\sigma }},
$$
for $x\in \Omega$.
It is not easy to describe the weight $\rho$ in general. However, when $\Omega$ is bounded and has a Lipschitz boundary, there exist two constants $C_1, C_2$ with $0<C_1 \leqslant C_2$, such that
$$
C_1 d(x ; \Gamma)^{-2\sigma} \leqslant \rho(x) \leqslant C_2 d(x ; \Gamma)^{-2\sigma}
$$
where $d(x, \Gamma)$ denotes the distance from $x$ to the boundary $\Gamma$ of $\Omega$.
I think that we can find the explicit formula of $C_2$ in the following way:
$$
\int_{\Omega^c} \frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+2\sigma}}  \leq \int_{B(x,d(x ; \Gamma))^c} \frac{dy}{|x-y|^{n+2\sigma}}=nV_n \int_{d(x ; \Gamma)}^{+\infty}\frac{r^{n-1}}{2\sigma r^{n+2\sigma}}dr=\frac{nV_n}{2\sigma}d(x ; \Gamma)^{-2\sigma},
$$
where $V_n=\frac{\pi^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}$. Thus, $C_2=\frac{nV_n}{2\sigma}$.
However, for $C_1$, I don't know why it exists and, if possible, how to find an explicit formula.
Also, when $C_1$ could be equal to $C_2$?
Thank you very much in advance.

A somewhat crude lower bound is $\frac{1}{|x|^p+|y|^p}\leq \frac{1}{|x-y|^p}$ , maybe this is enough to get something decent for $C_1$?

Actually, I think this is not necessary.... I will write an answer....

Oh nevermind, you want the lower bound to be in terms of $d(x;\partial\Omega)$ as well... I don't know how this can be achieved. You can of course produce estimates with the observations $$\Omega\subseteq \mathbb B(x_0,R) \ \Omega\subseteq\mathbb B(x,2R)$$
Where $x_0=\frac{1}{\mu^n(\Omega)}\int_{\Omega}x\mathrm d^n x$ is the center of mass of $\Omega$ and $R=\frac{1}{2}\sup_{x,y\in\Omega}|x-y|$ is the radius. But this does not produce a lower bound involving $d(x;\partial\Omega)$ ....

The lower bound is obtained by exploiting the uniform cone property of $\Omega$. For any $x$ as an interior point, find the $x'\in \Gamma$ such that the distance is achieved, and use the cylinder argument similar to the proof of Theorem 1.2.2.2 on $x'$. By shrinking $\Omega^c$ to just a small neighborhood around $x'$ (which can be represented using cylindrical coordinates by letting $x'$ as the origin), you will have the lower bound (which is more trivial than upper bound due to no improper integral is involved).

Thank you very much for your answers. Regarding the proof of Theorem 1.2.2.2, I've already tried to use it but couldn't get the desired lower bound with the term “distance to the boundary”.
